# Windows 7 mouse pointer not visible within Citrix Receiver window until window has focus

Tags: windows, windows-7, mouse, citrix

There is a very annoying problem with a Citrix Receiver window when I started remote desktop'ing into a Windows 7 machine.  This was not a problem when remote desktop'ing into Windows XP.

My Windows mouse pointer is invisible when the Citrix Receiver window (with Windows 7 not focused).  But when the window does have focus, I can clearly see the mouse pointer as I move the mouse pointer across that window.

How can I make it such that you can always see the mouse pointer?  Do you think it's a problem with the way Windows renders the mouse, or would this be a Citrix issue?  I'm thinking the former.

Why is this annoying? ... because I sometimes click in the wrong spot, which could compromise my workflow in Windows if I'm in the middle of doing work remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched the mouse pointer in Windows 7 (of the remote machine) from "Windows Aero" (default) to "Windows Black (large)" and now it works well!

Comment: Did not work for me (changing pointer to "Windows Black (large)." However, turning on "Pointer Trails" worked...but looks crummy.